# How to avoid duplicate values in maps using c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to write a program in C++ using maps...

My goal is to avoid the same values repeated in maps.

If the keys are same, we can use maps to avoid the duplicated keys. To allow duplicate keys, we use multimaps.

In case the value is the same, how can we avoid that?

The program which I have written allows duplicated values:

```
typedef std::map<int, std::string> MyMap;

int main()
{
    MyMap map;
    MyMap::iterator mpIter;

    int key;
    string value;

    int count;
    for(count = 0; count < 3;count++)
    {
        cin >> key;
        cin >> value;
               
        std::pair<MyMap::iterator, bool> res = map.insert(std::make_pair(key,value));
    }

    for (mpIter=map.begin(); mpIter != map.end(); ++mpIter)
         cout  << " "  << (*mpIter).second << endl;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `std::map` then

Comment: Or a Boost.Bimap with both sides being sets?

Comment: Check that the value is already present with map::find and skip it if it is there. What's your problem?

Comment: Could OP elaborate more? You want to have unique values, and keys do not matter? Or keys also have to be unique?

Comment: Map does not disallow duplicate values, only duplicate keys. Perhaps you should make an inverted index where the keys are the values you currently have and the values is now a list containing your current keys

Comment: You can create a reverse map with <string,int> and insert into it, if ok, then insert into `myMap` ;)

Answer (score 5):

Make the value part of the key and/or use a set but that may not really solve the problem. It isn't possible to easily define a container that has both unique keys AND values if that's what you want. However, you might still construct one. Here's a very simple example to illustrate what is needed:

```
// Assuming keys are KEY and values are VAL

class MyMap  {
public:
   std::set<KEY> keyset;
   std::set<VAL> valset;

   std::map<KEY,VAL> theRealMap;

   // assuming existence of  function HAS(S,V) 
   // which returns true if v is in set S
   bool MyInsert(KEY ky, VAL val) {
       if (HAS(keyset,  ky) return false;
       if (HAS(valset, val) return false;
       keyset.insert(ky);
       valset.insert(vl);
       return theRealMap.insert(std::pair<KEY,VAL>(ky, val));
   }
:
:
```

Since this is an example it's not intended to be copied. You will likely want to include the functionality provided by std:map. An easy way would be to use std::map as a base class  but you will need to hide (by making private) or implement similar code for each variant of insert otherwise you might get inadvertent insert that may not be unique.

Note: this requires twice the size of a single map. You can save some space by using theRealMap instead of a separate set for keys set. Another way would be to search the map but that sacrifices time for space. It's your call.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to maintain a separate [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) of the values. When you insert a value into a set it returns a `std::pair<iterator, bool>`. The `bool` value is `true` if the value was not already in the set. This tells you if it is safe to *also* put the value in the map.

First, however, you need to make sure the `key` is unique because the same `key` may already have been inserted with a *different value*:

```
typedef std::map<int, std::string> MyMap;

int main()
{
    MyMap map;
    MyMap::iterator mpIter;

    int key;
    string value;
    int count;

    // keep track of values with a std::set
    std::set<std::string> values;

    for(count = 0; count < 3; count++)
    {
        cin >> key;
        cin >> value;

        auto found = map.find(key);

        if(found != map.end()) // key already in map
            continue; // don't add it again

        // now try to add it to the set
        // only add to the map if its value is not already in the set
        if(values.insert(value).second)
            map.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
    }

    for(mpIter = map.begin(); mpIter != map.end(); ++mpIter)
        cout << " " << (*mpIter).second << endl;
}
```

Comment: I would go a step further, and try to come up with a custom container, that consists of a pair of `std::set`s, for both the key and a value, and something to tie a key in one, with a value in the other. Or a std::map+std::set, essentially your answer. Then, have this container meet as many requirements for a standard library container, as I need.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I would also make a custom container. But I feel that would be going a little beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 2):

One (inefficient) way to [do it](http://ideone.com/sFQJCF) is to **create a reverse map (with `<string,int>`) and insert your input in reverse order as that of `MyMap` into it.**  If ok, then insert into `MyMap`
Here is the working code.

```
typedef std::map<int, std::string> MyMap;

typedef std::map<string, int> rev_Map;
int main()
{
    MyMap map;
    rev_Map rmap;

    MyMap::iterator mpIter;
    rev_Map::iterator rmap_iter;

    int key;
    string value;
    int count;

    for(count = 0; count < 3;count++)
    {

            cin >> key;
            cin >> value;

            std::pair<rev_Map::iterator, bool> ok = rmap.insert(std::make_pair(value,key)); //insert into the reverse map

            if(ok.second) //if above amap.insert works

                std::pair<MyMap::iterator, bool> res = map.insert(std::make_pair(key,value));

    }

   for (mpIter=map.begin(); mpIter != map.end(); ++mpIter)
     cout  << " "  << (*mpIter).second << endl;
}
```